# MSBUILD RegexReplace get all text till 2nd last dot from end

Tags: regex, msbuild, regexp-replace, msbuildcommunitytasks

I am working with ToolsVersion="3.5".

I wanted to match from end of the string till 2-nd last dot (.).

For Example for given value **123.456.78.910.abcdefgh** I wanted to get **910.abcdefgh** only.

I tried with

```
<RegexReplace Input="$(big_number)" Expression="/(\w+\.\w+)$/gm" Replacement="$1" count="1">
        <Output ItemName ="big_number_tail" TaskParameter="Output"/>
</RegexReplace>
```

But it is returning entire string only.
Any idea what went wrong ?

Comment: In the expression, you are finding `x` and replacing it with `x` itself. You need to match the entire string and replace it with group 1 contents

Comment: Try ``Expression=".*\.([^.]*\.[^.]*)$" Replacement="$1"``

Comment: @GurmanjotSingh, Yes something is not right - not able to figure out what it is.
on https://regex101.com/ same expression is showing that it captures the required part, but not  sure why entire string is getting retuned with RegexReplace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, do not use a regex literal in a text attribute. When you define regex via strings, not code, regex literal notation (like `/.../gm`) is not usually used and in these cases `/` regex delimiters and `g`, `m`, etc. flags are treated as part of a pattern, and as a result, it never matches.

Besides, when you *extract via replacing* as here, you need to make sure you match the *whole* string with your pattern, and only capture the part you want to extract. Note you may have more than 1 capturing group, and then you could use `$2`, `$3`, etc. in the replacement.

You can use

```
<RegexReplace Input="$(big_number)" Expression=".*\.([^.]*\.[^.]*)$" Replacement="$1" count="1">
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7euPW1/1). *Details*:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\.` - a `.` char
- `([^.]*\.[^.]*)` - Group 1 (`$1` refers to this part): zero or more non-dot chars, a `.` char, and again zero or more chars other than dots
- `$` - end of string.